# Solve $a_0 = 1$, and $a_n = 3a_{n-1}$, for $n \in \Bbb Z_+$ using its characteristic equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

Solve $a_0 = 1$, and $a_n = 3a_{n-1}$, for $n \in \Bbb Z_+$ using the characteristic equation method.
This is my attempt:

> Characteristic polynomial is: $r^2 – 3r = r(r – 3)  $
>
> With roots $r_1 = 0$ and $r_2 = 3$.

Now I don't know do I need:

> $a_m = α⸱0^m + β⸱3^m$
>
> $a_0 = 1 = α⸱0^0 + β⸱3^0$

or only:

> $a_0 = 1 = α⸱0^0$

and I don't know how to finish it :(

Comment: You have a first order recurrence, so you should have a first order characteristic equation. It is $r-3=0$, not $r^2-3r=0$.

Comment: it's rather obvious that $a_n=3^n$, and that could be proved by induction

Comment: @almagest where do you see if it first order or second order recurrence? My discrete math textbook is not detailed in this section :(

Comment: how many previous terms does $a_n$ depend on?

Comment: Thank you J. W. Tanner. I guess I need to append "for all n ≥ 1" to your first answer above?

Comment: actually it's true for $n=0$ too